# JavaScript custom tap event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to create a custom event, such as tap, that would work both for mouse clicking and touch tapping an element, so it could be attached just like any other event. For now, I created a function that is mousedown/touchstart/pointerdown handler and I pass the actual handler to the data object, it works, but it's not elegant. Here it is:

```
var tap = function(e) {

  var handler=e.data.handler; //handler is passed in data object

  var eventType=e.originalEvent.type.replace('down','').replace('start',''); //touch, mouse or pointer
  var inputDevice=((eventType === 'pointer' && e.originalEvent.pointerType === 'mouse') || eventType === 'mouse') ? 'mouse' : 'touch';
  var endEvent=(eventType === 'touch') ? eventType+'end' : eventType+'up';
  var targetElement=this;

  e.preventDefault();

  $(document).on(endEvent+'.customTap', function(e) {

    var x,y;

    if (eventType === 'touch') {
        x=e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX;
        y=e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY;
    }
    else {
        x=e.clientX;
        y=e.clientY;
    }

    //this won't work, if the element has children, to do: iterate over parent elements
    if (document.elementFromPoint(x,y).isSameNode(targetElement)) handler(e); //execute the actual handler

    $(document).off(endEvent+'.customTap');
    e.preventDefault();

  });
}

var attachCustomTap = function($element, handler) {

    var startEvent;
    if (window.PointerEvent) startEvent='pointerdown';
    else startEvent='touchstart mousedown';

    $element.on(startEvent, { handler: handler }, tap);

}
```

So my question is, is it possible to use something like:

```
$('button').on('customTap', doSomething);
```

instead of

```
attachCustomTap($('button'), doSomething);
```

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Comment: I read that, but I can't see how this would help me, using this technique I would still have to attach handlers for pointerdown/touchstart just to trigger my custom event. My question is more like whether it is possible to call attachCustomTap function upon attaching the handler with .on().

Comment: I guess I will create a jQuery plugin and call it like $('button').customTap()

Comment: Think about it: your custom event doesn't exist right now. You can use `on` and tell it to listen for whatever event you want, but your event is never going to get fired unless you create it first.