# Tap (no realease) or click event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, mobile

I'd like to have an event fire whenever a user does a mouse click or a touchscreen tap.  I've tried using the "click" event, but on touchscreens it waits until the tap has finished and is more of a tap-and-release than a tap event.  It does not feel correct.

Is there an event which does either tap (no release) or click listening?

P.S. This question ([JavaScript custom tap event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386239/javascript-custom-tap-event)) is about jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no single event which represents the default "selection" action of both mouse and touch screen.  You can, though, use a mix of events.

The two most common events users expect to create a reaction are "click" and "touchstart", but you can't simply listen to both of those because the click event is generally triggered after the touchstart event (leading to a double trigger).

The following is some simple code for avoiding this issue:

```
function onTapOrClick(element, cb) {
    let debounce;  // temporarily disables on click events when touchstarts happen
    element.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
        if (debounce) { clearTimeout(debounce); }
        debounce = setTimeout(() => debounce = undefined, 1000);  // debounce is 1000ms, could easily be longer
        cb(event);
    });
    element.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        if (debounce) { return; }
        cb(event);
    });     
}
```